# R Mediation with continuous predictor and binary logistic regression models

Tags: r, logistic, continuous-data, predictor, mediation

I am running a mediation model using the r mediation package, but I am not getting the correct output for my variable types. I have a continuous predictor, but the output is treating my predictor as a categorical variable.

In short:

**Predictor** = cognitive test score [Composite_Z] (continuous)

**Mediator** = self-awareness [Awareness] (dichotomous; variable type = numerical in order to run mediation)

**Outcome** = driving frequency [DRFRQ] (dichotomous)

**10 Covariates** = Age (continuous), Sex (dichotomous), Race (dichotomous), Education (dichotomous), Severity (continuous), Time (continuous), Seizures (dichotomous), Income (ordinal), Motor (continuous), UrbanRural (ordinal)

I have two models that are going into my mediation analysis (both of these run fine without issues)--

***Model #1***: binary logistic regression examining the relationship between cognition (predictor) and self-awareness, while accounting for the covariates.

*R code:*

```
    fit.a.A3H1 <- glm(Awareness ~ Composite_Z + Age + Sex + Race +
 Education + Severity + Time + Seizures + Income + Motor 
+ UrbanRural, family=binomial(link="logit"), data=A3H1.df)
```

***Model #2***: binary logistic regression examining the relationship between cognition (predictor) and driving frequency (outcome), while accounting for self-awareness (mediator) and the covariates.

*R code:*

```
    fit.total.A3H1 <- glm(DRFRQ ~ Composite_Z + Awareness + Age + Sex 
+ Race + Education + Severity + Time + Seizures + Income 
+ Motor + UrbanRural, family=binomial(link="logit"), data = A3H1.df)
```

***Mediation model***: Then, I put those models (outlined above) into my mediation analysis. I am using the R *mediation* package to run the analysis.

*R code:*

```
fitMed.A3H1 <- mediate(fit.a.A3H1, fit.total.A3H1, sims=1000, boot=FALSE, 
                       treat="Composite_Z", mediator="Awareness",
                       covariates = NULL, use_speed = FALSE)
```

*Output:*

```
Causal Mediation Analysis 

Quasi-Bayesian Confidence Intervals

                          Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value  
ACME (control)           -0.001007    -0.004191         0.00    0.27  
ACME (treated)           -0.000686    -0.002933         0.00    0.27  
ADE (control)             0.031882     0.003696         0.06    0.03 *
ADE (treated)             0.032203     0.003727         0.06    0.03 *
Total Effect              0.031196     0.004744         0.05    0.03 *
Prop. Mediated (control) -0.024010    -0.134304         0.08    0.25  
Prop. Mediated (treated) -0.016399    -0.113058         0.07    0.25  
ACME (average)           -0.000846    -0.003507         0.00    0.27  
ADE (average)             0.032042     0.003711         0.06    0.03 *
Prop. Mediated (average) -0.020204    -0.124782         0.08    0.25  

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Sample Size Used: 350 

Simulations: 1000
```

The output gives the results in groups, even though my predictor is a continuous variable. **Does anyone know why I'm running into this problem and ways I could fix it?** Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What's also strange is that I do not have this problem when I run a separate mediation analysis with the same predictor/mediator/covariates (but a different outcome variable that is continuous instead of dichotomous). This separate mediation analysis is made up of a (1) binary logistic regression model and (2) linear regression model, and the output shows only the overall ACME/ADE/etc (i.e., there are not groups).

Comment: when you say dichotomous you mean 2 values?

Comment: @RalphWinters Yes, the dichotomous variables have 2 levels/values. For example, self-awareness has two values: 0 and 1.

Comment: So the response variable from the glm is continuous?  You should be using not be using family=binary.  Try family=Gaussian.  That is for continuous variables

Comment: @RalphWinters The response variable is dichotomous/binary in both of the glm (i.e., model #1 and model #2)

Comment: Most of the examples I have seen for this looks like the output breaks out to an estimate of average causal and average direct effects.  But I have never worked with this package.  Maybe someone who is more familiar with this can help you. Good luck!

Comment: @Christina, I agree with you that it is confusing to have separated output for supposed control and treatment groups in regards to a numeric variable. My understanding is that you should youse the ACME (average) and the ADE (average) outputs in your analyses. I hope this helps.